# Contours Not Plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I'm trying to plot contours of ash deposit depth using `Basemap` and `matplotlib`. For some reason, my contours aren't showing up and I can't see what I'm missing.

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from netCDF4 import Dataset
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

url = "BigAsh_DepoThick.nc"
data = Dataset(url, mode="r")

times = data.variables["time"]
lats = data.variables["Lat"][:]
lons = data.variables["Lon"][:]
depths = data.variables["DepoThick"][:,:,:]

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))

# Create the map
m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-150,llcrnrlat=10,urcrnrlon=-60,urcrnrlat=70,
        projection='merc', resolution ='l')

m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=1)
m.drawstates(linewidth=1)
m.drawcountries(linewidth=1)

m.fillcontinents(color='gray')

plons, plats = np.meshgrid(lons, lats)
x, y = m(plons, plats)
cp = m.contourf(x, y, depths[-1,:,:], 100)

cbar = plt.colorbar(cp)
cbar.set_label("Ash Depth [mm]")
plt.title("Mt. St. Helens Ash Depth")

plt.show()
```

Comment: No warning, no error, and no contour plot? What about the colorbar? Have you tried setting an explicit colormap? (I don't think this should help, but still)

Comment: Is it possible that `depths[-1,:,:]` is all `None`?

Comment: No, I've actually used the same data to create contour plots without the Basemap.

Comment: @WillLuce Did you solve the problem? If yes, than what is the way?